# How to save a BOOL in iOS app

Tags: ios, save, boolean, nsuserdefaults

I used the following code to save a `BOOL` but it's not working.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"save"];
StrongMAN = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"save"];
```

Are there other ways to save a `BOOL`?

Comment: Any integer other than `0` is represented as `true` or `YES` in Objective C, so you can also achieve this by saving an `int` however, you should call the `synchronize` method to solve your problem with current code

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: No, this is not needed.

Comment: @rmaddy OP's question probably relates to the setting of the value and then quickly check if it is done. So from the docs: Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"kLogIn"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: The call to `synchronize` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"testingBool"];
BOOL test = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"testingBool"];
```